# Is there a Photoshop Alt+Drag equivalent in GIMP?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, layers, selections

Is there a Photoshop Alt+Drag equivalent in GIMP, where you copy a selected object and drag it in a layer? All I can find is [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/24784009/Alt-Move-Photoshop-equivalent-in-GIMP.html#comments), but it's under a paywall.

Comment: Please consider editing and stating in words what Alt+Drag does for you in Photoshop, because not all users here have Photoshop; especially those who focus on tools like GIMP.

Comment: I have already stated that.

Comment: So you select any object, then keep ALT pressed and drag it to a layer-symbol and you get a copy (in the same location?) in some other layer?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a direct equivalent, but the same is possible using a couple of different methods.

**Method 1**

You can duplicate a layer using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then use the move tool to move the layer.

Here's an example. I've cropped the layer to its content (Layer > Crop to Content) so you can see it more clearly, although this isn't necessary. There's no need to make an actual selection of the object as this works on the currently selected layer. The yellow dotted line shown here is the layer boundary, not a selection.

[image]

**Method 2:**

The following doesn't create additional layers.

1. Make a selection and copy it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. Paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which will create a floating selection
3. Move the floating selection using the Move tool <kbd>M</kbd>.
4. Keep repeating the paste and move as often as you want. Then once you have enough duplicates, hit Anchor or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to anchor the floating selection to the current layer.

An example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In most selection tools (rectangle, ellipse, lasso, wand, color...), without exiting the tool, you can Alt-Ctrl-Drag to cut and move your selection (selection contents and selection mask). You still have to anchor it (Ctrl-H) afterwards.